# C# LibVLCSharp: SetAudioDevice - error 0x80070057

Tags: libvlcsharp

How can I change the output device?

```
MediaPlayer.SetOutputDevice(id);
```

I have picked out the Id via the AudioOutputDeviceEnum.

VLC says:

> mmdevice Debug: using selected device
> {536A131C-2830-445B-8ACC-EDD22DDCE6D5} mmdevice Error: cannot get
> selected device {536A131C-2830-445B-8ACC-EDD22DDCE6D5} (error
> 0x80070057) mmdevice Error: cannot get device identifier (error
> 0x80070057)

I would like to achieve passthrough of the audio signal

Comment: Does it work in VLC?

Comment: Does it work on another computer?

Comment: Are your drivers up to date?

Comment: I get the same error: mmdevice audio output error: cannot get selected device {25c3886c-f987-4983-9599-2d46bd85f34b} (error 0x80070057)